# accessibilityTraits support in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

in my IPhone application I use `textFieldMain.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently;`
It works fine in ios 6 but not work in ios 7. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I haven't experienced any issues with "updates frequently" on iOS7. Can you tell me more about how you are using it? Is it a text field that updates frequently? What other than the user would cause an update in your app?

Comment: Yes, I just verified on out app that it works as expected on a label on iOS 7