# What is UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently in iOS UIAccessibility?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm developing application which is also for blind people. I'm using UITextField, where 508/VA(Professional Testing team) asking us to implement `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently`. I went through documentation from Apple, but I didn't got any methods where I can observe `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently` notification.

I have same kind question like

[UITextView setup for Voice Over to select/read by paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920012/uitextview-setup-for-voice-over-to-select-read-by-paragraph)

[accessibilityTraits support in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158796/accessibilitytraits-support-in-ios-7)

but I'm not getting how to use this `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently`.I'm not getting any notification method for this.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are not expected to process notifications for `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently`. Accessibility elements advertise traits describing their behavior. The updates frequently trait is intended to inform accessibility clients that an element's content changes very often, perhaps even too often for users to perceive every change. When VoiceOver encounters an element with this trait, it announces the value at periodic intervals rather than with every single change.

For a more detailed explanation of `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently`, see this [blog post by Keith Harrison](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/04/23/voiceover-accessibility.html). You may also find Apple's [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW7) helpful (especially the linked section on traits).